# How do I get user_ids where any association updated_at is within a range?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to put together an ActiveRecord query that will return any user id where the associated model records were updated within a specific range.

So for example `User has_many :searches` and `has_many :lists`. I want to do something like this:

```
user_ids = [1,2,3,4]
search_users = Search.where(user_id: user_ids).where("updated_at > ?", 7.days.ago).pluck(:user_id)
list_users = List.where(user_id: user_ids).where("updated_at > ?", 7.days.ago).pluck(:user_id)
ids_i_care_about = (list_users + search_users).uniq
```

So across multiple models, I need to get user_ids that have updated_at in my range for any of the models.  (The time range only needs to satisfy at least 1 model's updated_at). I'm doing this for about a 12 or so models that each have a user_id.

What's the best way to do this in ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [search-logic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) gem to write queries like this.

```
User.searches_updated_at_eq(start_date..end_date).lists_updated_at_eq(start_date..end_date).map(&:id)
```

Hope this answered your question.